# Does a constant Radon-Nikodym derivative imply the measures are multiples of each other?

Tags: probability, distributions, measure-theory

Let $(\mathsf{X}, \mathcal{X})$ be a measurable space and $\pi$ and $\mu$ be two probability measures on it such that $\pi \ll \mu$ with constant Radon-Nikodym derivative
$$
\frac{d\pi}{d\mu} = \text{constant}
$$

> Does this imply that the measures are multiples of each other? I.e. that there exists a constant $c > 0$ such that
> $$
> \pi(\mathsf{A}) = c\mu(\mathsf{A}) \qquad \forall\,\mathsf{A}\in\mathcal{X}
> $$

Comment: If both $\pi$ and $\mu$ are **probability** measures, then $c$ must be $1$.  In other words, $\pi \equiv \mu$.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  From the definition of what the [Radon-Nikodym derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem) is (which is essentially a type of anti-integral), for any event $\mathcal{A} \in \mathscr{X}$ and any measures $\pi$ and $\mu$ obeying the requirements you have given, we must have:

$$\begin{align}
\pi(\mathcal{A}) 
&= \int \limits_\mathcal{A} \frac{d\pi}{d\mu} \ d \mu \\[6pt]
&= \int \limits_\mathcal{A} \text{constant}  \ d \mu \\[6pt]
&= \text{constant} \times \int \limits_\mathcal{A} \ d \mu \\[12pt]
&= \text{constant} \times \mu(\mathcal{A}), \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

which shows that the measures are proportionate in this case, with the constant of proportionality equal to the constant value for the Radon-Nikodym derivative.  If $\pi$ and $\mu$ are both *probability* measures then they must both obey the [norming axiom of probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms#Second_axiom), which means they must both have a total measure of one.  In this case you have $\text{constant} = 1$ and so $\pi = \mu$ (i.e., they are the same probability measure).  (This is why when we work with probability, showing proportionality is sufficient to show that two distributions are the same.)